# JQuery Fade in fade out animation not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need some help with animation. 
Look at this sample video I've created
for question 1 going to question 2 the transition is smooth, however for the question two going to 3 and so on it doesn't work.

https://www.loom.com/share/b1a1f658f7174242929eb7b7a7609943

```
 <div class="selection">
                <div class="container qblock1 active ">
                    <h4>Are you currently insured?</h4>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col"><a href="#" class="quizbtn" data-next="qblock2">YES</a></div>
                        <div class="col"><a href="#" class="quizbtn" data-next="qblock2">NO</a></div>
                        <!--
                        <div class="w-100"></div>
                        <div class="col"><a href="#">TOYOTA</a></div>
                        <div class="col"><a href="#">DODGE</a></div>
                        <div class="w-100"></div>
                        <div class="col"><a href="#">NISSAN</a></div>
                        <div class="col"><a href="#">HONDA</a></div>
                        <div class="w-100"></div>
                        <div class="col selected"><a href="#">HYUNDAI</a></div>
                        <div class="col"><a href="#">CHRYSLER</a></div>-->
                    </div>
                </div>
    <!-- Question 2 -->
                <div class="container inactive qblock2">
                    <h4>Question Text 2?</h4>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col"><a href="#" class="quizbtn" data-next="qblock3">Test2</a></div>
                        <div class="col"><a href="#" class="quizbtn" data-next="qblock3">Test2</a></div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                 <!-- Question 3 -->
                 <div class="container inactive  qblock3">
                    <h4>Question Text 3?</h4>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col"><a href="#" class="quizbtn" data-next="qblock4">Test3</a></div>
                        <div class="col"><a href="#" class="quizbtn" data-next="qblock4">Test3</a></div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                 <!-- Question 3 -->
                 <div class="container inactive  qblock4">
                    <h4>Question Text 4?</h4>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col"><a href="#" class="quizbtn" data-next="Success">Test4</a></div>
                        <div class="col"><a href="#" class="quizbtn" data-next="Success">Test4</a></div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>




  $(document).ready(function() {
        let next = 1;
        $('.quizbtn').click(function() {

                $('.qblock'+ next++).fadeOut(400).addClass('inactive');
                $('.qblock'+ next).fadeIn("fast").addClass("active");

        });

    });
```

Comment: Is there any CSS involved? Create a [mcve]

Comment: Just the display: none for the inactive divs.